# Hadoop- I want to load a table in hive using a file in hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I am not able to create a file in local. Can you please tell me how and where to create a sample local file. I am bit confused about and local and hdfs.How to move the file from local to HDFS and once after moving how i can check the file is in hdfs. I am very new to hadooop.

Thanks ,
Ram

Comment: can someone provide some insight on this?

Comment: Error messages? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in Linux based OS

**Create a file using**:  `$ nano /path/to/file.txt` .

You must have sufficient priviledge in  directory where you create the file.

**To move the file to HDFS** ( As a user privileged to access HDFS, say hdfs user ) :

`hadoop fs -put /path/to/file.txt`

**To check the file :** `hadoop fs -ls /user/<hadoop user>`

**To check the content of file :** `hadoop fs -cat /user/<hadoop user>/file.txt`

Now you can create a Hive table using create external table .. and mention the path of file in HDFS.